# CSS image's container scaling with a 100% height

Tags: html, css, image-scaling

I'm using an image which must auto-scale inside a div whose height is defined by the root div.
The scaling is fine in all major browsers, using `height: 100%` on the image itself.
But it seems that on some browsers, the image container doesn't adapt its width accordingly to its content (the image).

Check by yourself the [**live demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/uJMce/3/).

This demo uses an image container with a blue background.

**Expected behavior:** This background shouldn't display since the container width and height should be the same as its content (the image).

**Actual behavior**:

- On Chrome 11, Safari 5 and IE9, the behavior is as expected.

[image: On Chrome 12]
<sub>(source: [imgh.us](https://imgh.us/Screen_shot_2011-04-29_at_2.55.43_PM.png))</sub>

- On Firefox 3.6/4.0 and Opera 11, the behavior is not as expected: the blue background is displayed.

[image: On Opera 11]
<sub>(source: [imgh.us](https://imgh.us/Screen_shot_2011-04-29_at_2.56.04_PM.png))</sub>

What is the root cause of this strong difference between major browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of Firefox, this looks like a bug.  I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=653739

You can work around by removing the `overflow:hidden` unless you actually need it.

Comment: Nice. Actually I can't work around by removing the `overflow:hidden`. I need the div width to be correct so that I can add other content inside, as you can see when hovering the live demo.

Comment: In that case, your best workaround is to set the pixel height or `inherit` on the child of the `overflow:hidden` div in addition to the `overflow:hidden` div, instead of using `100%`.

Comment: That is a nice complement of two7s_clash explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Those later browsers interpret `inline-block` more strictly (correctly).

That is, your element is positioned inline (like a span), but the element's contents are laid out as if the element were a block.

Comment: Interesting. Seems that you're just plain right! You must be the author of http://jsfiddle.net/uJMce/5/ ? If this is the case, would you be able to prevent from using a fixed `top` value for the `.ui` CSS class? The fact is that I can't know what will be the size of the picture in my real case scenario. Hence, this should be generic.

Comment: @Aranud No, thats not me. Looks like you changed your demo and that you're now asking a different question.

Comment: Actually I changed the demo link to reflect the answer I assumed was yours. Anyway, your answer is correct, and if there is no better proposition (like a workaround), the point will be yours.